# How to put text on an image

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to write text over an image with the CSS and HTML below  but it's not working..

**CSS**

```
.social_media_head{
background: url(newsletter_image.gif) no-repeat center;
position: relative;
right: -9px;
height: 0;
width: 325px;
padding: 30px 0 0 5px;     
}

.media_name h2{
position: relative;
top: 2px;
}

.media_name {
position: relative;
top: 2px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
    <div class="social_media_head">
    <h2 class="media_name">Social Media</h2>
    </div>
```

Example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fCUTm/)

**Update**
I'm very sorry if the image I'm referring to is wrong. The image I want to put text on is the image on top of the social media icons (facebook, twitter, youtube)...i.e. Image inside class = "social_media_head".

Once again I'm sorry for the confussion.

Comment: The text is on top of the image. At least when I look at it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fCUTm/ you need to change padding to margin, and set hight to height of image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this by setting z-index of text higher than image and position absolute

```
.text{
z-index:101;
position:absolute;
/set the position of text you want
}

.image{
z-index:100;
}
```

and to text above image

`.media_name h2` should be `h2.media_name`

```
h2.media_name {
    color: red;
    margin-top: -30px;

    top: 2px;
}
```

[**full screen Result**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ej5CX/embedded/result/) and [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ej5CX/)

Comment: @DotunnNnnn what do you want?

Comment: @DotunnNnnn quick solution 
`.media_name {
    color: red;
    margin-top: -30px;
    
    top: 2px;
}`

Comment: if you dont want left space remove 5px padding in `social_media_head padding:30px 0 0 0; `

Answer (score 1):

Try the following to avoid H-tags, and for the box to adjust for height the image is inline rather than as background: ([see code here http://jsfiddle.net/jySZB/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/jySZB/1/))

(due to update, the old code is removed and kept in the link above - see new link and code below) -

UPDATE: if "over an image" means above rather than on top (which *do* make more sense in this case), try this code instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/jySZB/2/

HTML:

```
<div class="social_media_head">
    <div>Social Media</div>
    <img src="http://satcomng.com/types/twitter.png" alt="" />
    <img src="http://satcomng.com/types/twitter.png" alt="" />
    <img src="http://satcomng.com/types/twitter.png" alt="" />
</d
```

CSS:

```
.social_media_head {
    display:block;
}
.social_media_head div {
    color:red;
    font-size:26px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    clear:both;
}
```

Result:

[image: result 2]

Tip: as the images are inline here they are easy to convert to click-able links to go the the social sites (I used only one image for example).

Comment: Aha, by "over an image" you mean *above* those images?

Comment: The image in this class is what I want to put text on class =
"social_media_head"

Answer (score 0):

Works for me (simplified): http://jsbin.com/uqazel/1/

Maybe you need to set an appropriate `height`.